# python create subset of array from boolean column mask

Tags: python, numpy

I need to create a function or equation that will turn this input...

```
a = [True, False, True]
b = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

into this output...

```
c = [[1, 3], [4, 6], [7, 9]]
```

Note: the above arrays are all numpy arrays. Thanks!

Comment: then add `numpy` tag

Comment: Something like `[[e for x, e in zip(a, sublist) if x] for sublist in b]` will work but I suspect there's a more efficent numpy solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`numpy` solution

```
import numpy as np 
a = np.array([True, False, True])
b = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
b[:,a]

array([[1, 3],
       [4, 6],
       [7, 9]])
```

Comment: Nice, makes much more sense +1

Answer (score 2):

You can use itertools compress

```
from itertools import compress
c = [list(compress(i, a)) for i in b]

[[1, 3], [4, 6], [7, 9]]
```